# How to check a permission which is declared in manifest are not using anywhere in my App?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Is there any way to find the android permission is a part of your App?
Because I have added many permissions 3 years before and I am really confused about which permission I have used for which purpose?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
```

These are my lifetime permissions used in my App?

Comment: Maybe lint gives you some warning. Not sure though

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html+

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on permission and choose "Find Usages" option. You can see usage of that permission in the app codes.

Comment: Like for example if permission is <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> should I only have to find this 'BLUETOOTH' ?

Comment: No. There is option in menu pop up  for find usage

Comment: It says "Cannot search for usages. Position to an element to find usages for, and try again.? " on every find usage?

Comment: Is your cursor over permission line?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Merged Manifest. It will have all the permmissions you have Used.

Merged Manifest Can be located like we move from design to text in an xml file.

### OR

Move to Permmissions and right click on permission and choose **Find Usages or use ALT F7** option.